# Polygons showing in shading/render

Tags: texturing

I exported a heightfield from houdini into blender and assigned a material with textures. In some areas its fine but in others polygons are showing. And with just a normal P. BSDF its not showing. I'm lost. I tried different types of unwrapping and texture coordinates but no fix. help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the heightfield image file compressed? It is best to export as OpenEXR 32-Bit FLoat without compression

Comment: i didnt export as heightmap, its exported as geometry

Comment: Could you cut a small problematic chunk of it out, and share on https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=VMBlWm88" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/VMBlWm88/)